# How to Inject Dependencies to Dynamically Loaded Assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have a manager class that loads various plug-in modules contained in separate assemblies through reflection. This modules are communication to the outside world (WebAPI, various other web protocols).

```
public class Manager
{
   public ILogger Logger; // Modules need to access this.

   private void LoadAssemblies()
   {
     // Load assemblies through reflection.
   }
}
```

These plug-in modules must communicate with an object contained within the manager class. How can I implement this? I thought about using dependency injection/IoC container, but how can I do this across assemblies?

Another thought that I had, that I am not thrilled with, is to have the modules reference a static class containing the resource that they need.

I appreciate any constructive comments/suggestions.

Comment: How do you instantiate instances of these plug-ins? Do they implement one or more interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ioc containers should support this. For example, with autofac you might do:

```
// in another assembly
class plugin {
   // take in required services in the constructor
   public plugin(ILogger logger) { ... }
}

var cb = new ContainerBuilder();

// register services which the plugins will depend on
cb.Register(cc => new Logger()).As<ILogger>();

var types = // load types
foreach (var type in types) {
    cb.RegisterType(type); // logger will be injected
}

var container = cb.Build();
// to retrieve instances of the plugin
var plugin = cb.Resolve(pluginType);
```

Depending on how the rest of your app will call the plugins, you can alter the registrations appropriately (e. g. register with AsImplementedInterfaces() to retrieve the plugin by a known interface or Keyed to retrieve the plugin by some key object (e. g. a string)).

Comment: How would I accomplish this with Ninject?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion, I'm having a problem. My class that loads assemblies and injects all their dependencies resides in an isolated library. This library has all of its dependencies injected into it via constructor injection. The IoC container resides in my consumer app (The consumer app might not be even using a container!).

So, how can I potentially inject all the dependencies of the dynamically loaded objects without accessing the container, and without explicitly requesting every single dependency from the constructor? Is MEF the answer?

Comment: @ShervinShahrdar typically with the IOC pattern you want to be wiring everything together at the top level (the consumer app). Either lower level libraries are container-aware or they are not (although you can strike a middle position by depending on a generalized container interface like `System.IServiceProvider`). In general if you have a library trying to do IOC-style registrations and wiring it's typically best to make that library aware of the container. With Autofac, the "modules" concept provides a natural approach to library-sourced registrations and setup.