# Dynamic connection System.DirectoryServices through System.Reflection

Tags: c#, system.reflection, directoryservices

I have simple task - get DNS name of PC by computer name from AD.

In standard variant, no problem:

```
string computerName = "somePC";

var search = new DirectorySearcher
        {
            Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=computer)(sAMAccountName={computerName}$))"
        };
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dNSHostName");

var result = search.FindOne();

var dnsName = result.Properties["dNSHostName"][0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(dnsName);
```

But in my situation, I can connect assembly only dynamically through `System.Reflection`.

I know it's bad variant. But I don't have any other way.

I never used this setup and can't understand how I can do it....

At the beginning, I connect DLL, create class instances and get some properties and methods:

```
        string computerName = "somePC";
        string filter = $"(&(objectCategory=computer)(sAMAccountName={computerName}$))";

        System.Reflection.Assembly dsAsm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Project\System.DirectoryServices.dll");

        Type searchClass = dsAsm.GetType("System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher");
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo filterDSprop = searchClass.GetProperty("Filter");
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo proploadDSprop = searchClass.GetProperty("PropertiesToLoad");
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo findoneDSmethod = searchClass.GetMethod("FindOne");

        Type searchResultClass = dsAsm.GetType("System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult");
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertiesProp = searchResultClass.GetProperty("Properties");
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo getentryDSmethod = searchResultClass.GetMethod("GetDirectoryEntry");
```

After these I must using Activator and Invoke? But I don't understand how I can use methods and properties and get value (dnsname).

Can you help me?

Comment: Why? Why can't use use a built-in .NET assembly normally? You *have* to load it to for the application to run after all. `But i don't have otherway.` Why? What does that mean? If you don't want to specify the concrete type you can use `dynamic`, no need for reflection.

Comment: Your code won't work at all without System.DirectoryServices. Instead of trying to load DirectoryServices dynamically, you should probably put *this* code into a separate assembly and load it. You could put your own code in a class implementing a common interface, so you'd only need reflection to instantiate that class and access it through the interface

Comment: I can't using assembly noramally because it's C# code injection in proprietarity RPA application. This application can't support adding additional assembly and have built standatrt assemblies. I don't have any interface for adding assembly.

Comment: That doesn't explain the problem or allow anyone to create a solution. Although it looks like the *real* problem is how to create a plugin, not how to use reflection. You'd have to consult that product's API guide to see how to use plugins. .NET Framework itself provides the [MEF classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) for this. Most DI containers can also work with dynamically loaded dependencies, directly or indirectly [as this question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693427/how-to-inject-dependencies-to-dynamically-loaded-assemblies)

Comment: For example, in the worst case, you can load an assembly, create a concrete instance of the type you want and register it as a singleton or transient eg with `services. RegisterSingleton(myObject)`

Comment: The concept of the plugin/addin architecture remains the same. Put *your* code in the plugin and load it dynamically. You'll be able to write your code normally and only expose an interface with the methods the parent application needs to know about

Comment: I don't have access to API and creating plugins. Why i can't use these way? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial

Comment: But that's what you try to do - use `System.DirectoryServices` as if it were a plugin. The solution remains the same - put *your* code in the external library. Load that library, instantiate your main class and call it. That's a *lot* easier than trying to write 10 reflection lines for each single method call

Comment: In any case you you can't say what the problem is, you can't get an answer. All products are proprietary but that doesn't mean you can't ask for help with Visual Studio or Oracle. That's what SO is for. What's the *actual* problem, *actual* restrictions? Why do you assume *reflection* is a desirable or eve possible solution? Whose going to deploy that assembly for example?

Comment: I think I understand you ) I'll try.

Comment: BTW `get DNS name of PC by computer name from AD.` you don't need AD for that. You need **DNS**. You need to make the correct call to return the computer's name. [Environment.MachineName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename?view=netframework-4.8) will get you the NetBIOS name. [Dns.GetHostName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostname?view=netframework-4.8) will return the DNS name.

Comment: And [Dns.GetHostEntry(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Dns_GetHostEntry_System_String_) allows you to resolve any name or address

Comment: I'm processing list netBIOS name of other PC (not my PC). Environment.MachineName not variant.

Comment: In source i have only NetBIOS names. Some NetBIOS names not equal DNS name, because cut after 15 symbools. At this situation i can't getting IP through Dns.GetHostName by NetBIOS, only DNS.